# D3 bar char x-axis line not displaying

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to draw a line in x-axis (bottom of bars in the chart) using the following script but it draws the on the top. What is the correct way of adding line on the bottom? Please help me to solve it.

```
var datasetBarChart = ${barList};


// set initial group value
var group = "All";

function datasetBarChosen(group) {
    var ds = [];
    for (x in datasetBarChart) {
        if (datasetBarChart[x].group == group) {
            ds.push(datasetBarChart[x]);
        }
    }
    return ds;
}


function dsBarChartBasics() {

    var margin = {top: 30, right: 5, bottom: 20, left: 50},
    width = 1000 - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = 450 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
            colorBar = d3.scale.category20(),
            barPadding = 1
            ;

    return {
        margin: margin,
        width: width,
        height: height,
        colorBar: colorBar,
        barPadding: barPadding
    }
    ;
}

function dsBarChart() {

    var firstDatasetBarChart = datasetBarChosen(group);

    var basics = dsBarChartBasics();

    var margin = basics.margin,
            width = basics.width,
            height = basics.height,
            colorBar = basics.colorBar,
            barPadding = basics.barPadding
            ;

    var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([0, firstDatasetBarChart.length])
            .range([0, width])
            ;

    // Create linear y scale 
    // Purpose: No matter what the data is, the bar should fit into the svg area; bars should not
    // get higher than the svg height. Hence incoming data needs to be scaled to fit into the svg area.  
    var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
            // use the max funtion to derive end point of the domain (max value of the dataset)
            // do not use the min value of the dataset as min of the domain as otherwise you will not see the first bar
            .domain([0, d3.max(firstDatasetBarChart, function (d) {
                    return d.measure;
                })])
            // As coordinates are always defined from the top left corner, the y position of the bar
            // is the svg height minus the data value. So you basically draw the bar starting from the top. 
            // To have the y position calculated by the range function
            .range([height, 0])
            ;

    //Create SVG element

    var svg = d3.select("#barChart")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .attr("id", "barChartPlot")

            ;

    var plot = svg
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
            ;

    var median = svg.append("line")

            .attr("x2", width)
            .attr("y2", (xScale/width))
            .attr("stroke-width", 2)
            .attr("stroke", "black");

    plot.selectAll("rect")
            .data(firstDatasetBarChart)
            .enter()
            .append("rect")
            .attr("x", function (d, i) {
                return xScale(i);
            })
            .attr("width", width / firstDatasetBarChart.length - barPadding)
            .attr("y", function (d) {
                return yScale(d.measure);
            })
            .attr("height", function (d) {
                return height - yScale(d.measure);
            })
            .attr("fill", "lightgrey")
            ;


    // Add y labels to plot 

    plot.selectAll("text")
            .data(firstDatasetBarChart)
            .enter()
            .append("text")
            .text(function (d) {
                return formatAsInteger(d3.round(d.measure));
            })
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            // Set x position to the left edge of each bar plus half the bar width
            .attr("x", function (d, i) {
                return (i * (width / firstDatasetBarChart.length)) + ((width / firstDatasetBarChart.length - barPadding) / 2);
            })
            .attr("y", function (d) {
                return yScale(d.measure) + 14;
            })
            .attr("class", "yAxis")
            /* moved to CSS            
             .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
             .attr("font-size", "11px")
             .attr("fill", "white")
             */
            ;

    // Add x labels to chart    

    var xLabels = svg
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + (margin.top + height) + ")")
            ;

    xLabels.selectAll("text.xAxis")
            .data(firstDatasetBarChart)
            .enter()
            .append("text")
            .text(function (d) {
                return d.category;
            })
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            // Set x position to the left edge of each bar plus half the bar width
            .attr("x", function (d, i) {
                return (i * (width / firstDatasetBarChart.length)) + ((width / firstDatasetBarChart.length - barPadding) / 2);
            })
            .attr("y", 15)
            .attr("class", "xAxis")
            //.attr("style", "font-size: 12; font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif")
            ;

    // Title

    svg.append("text")
            .attr("x", (width + margin.left + margin.right) / 2)
            .attr("y", 15)
            .attr("class", "title")
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .text Breakdown 2015")
            ;
}

dsBarChart();
```

script for the line;

```
 var median = svg.append("line")

            .attr("x2", width)
            .attr("y2", (xScale/width))
            .attr("stroke-width", 2)
            .attr("stroke", "black");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite understand your y2 attribute. It looks like you want the line to render as `<line x1="0" y1="{height}" x2="{width}" y2="{height}" />`

Ideally you want to express this in terms of your scale functions so if they change you won't have to update this statement. The corresponding d3 call for that would be:

```
var median = svg.append("line")
                .attr("stroke-width", 2)
                .attr("stroke", "black")
                .attr("x1", xScale.range()[0])
                .attr("x2", xScale.range()[1])
                .attr("y1", yScale.range()[0])
                .attr("y2", yScale.range()[0]);
```

Also, I think something is up with the `xScale/width` calculation. xScale is a function. Though you should look into [d3.svg.axis](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes) too